# Observe when UITabBar is Hidden from Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

How do I add an observer for when a UITabBar is hidden (through 'hides-bottom-bar-when-pushed')? I have a custom button that sits underneath my tab bar and I want to make sure it doesn't appear when the UITabBar is hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to place your `UIToolbar` inside a `UIView` that has clipping enabled and position the clip-view just above the `UITabBar`. Then add this `UIView` as a subview of your `UITabBar`. This way showing and hiding the `UITabBar` will automatically show or hide your `UIToolbar` Now you can animate the showing and hiding of your `UIToolbar` and still have it disappear each time the `UITabBar` does.

Comment: tabbar in UITabBarController is just read-only,how could you add a subview on it?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will tell you when the value of that field changes:

```
 UITabBar *myTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] init];

 [self addObserver:myInterestedObjectWhoWantsToKnowWhenTabBarHiddenChanges
        forKeyPath:@"myTabBar.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed"
           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
           context:nil];
```

Then in myInterestedObjectWhoWantsToKnowWhenTabBarHiddenChanges.m, implement

```
     - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                  ofObject:(id)object 
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {    

               if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myTabBar.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed"]) {  // this key must match, where observer is set.        
                    // object will be "self" from the code above
                    // and the change dictionary will have the old and new values.
               }
       }
```